# How to Achieve Animatable Menu in Android UI

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, menu

Someday i was searching for Menu designs and i found out this GIF.

[This Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj9hb.gif)

Could anyone tell me how can i make this?
Is this is any 3rd party API or framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui) you can find a lot awesome material design libs.
Speaking of the example, you can create onScrollChangedListener(), and then you can to start animation for each icon when the scroll has been started and ended.